# XAML textbox updated when Textis entered in input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a bunch of inputs that are being used to collect information.  These inputs need to update the listname textbox on update.

I need to display it as Last Name space Suffix, First Name space Middle Initial.  the Parth on each input is setting the text thats typed into the code to save it to the database on update.  I am not sure where to go from here.  Do I use a one way or two way mode? do I write it in c# and how?

```
<TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Tag="{Binding Path=FirstNameLabel, Source={StaticResource Clientization}}" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="35"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Tag="Middle" MinWidth="75" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="30"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.MiddleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding Path=LastNameLabel, Source={StaticResource Clientization}}" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="60"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Tag="Suffix" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="20"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.Suffix, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Tag="List Name*" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="160"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.ListName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="TextBox_6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Tag="NPI*" Style="{StaticResource EditTextBox}" MaxLength="80"
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=HideNpi, Source={StaticResource Clientization}, Converter={StaticResource TernaryConverter}, ConverterParameter='True ? Collapsed : Visible'}"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Provider.NPI, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Entity Framework with your WPF application to binding with database, please check out below links for your reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/dd776537

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/dd776540

And this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716735.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using EF is out of the questoin for this project